# List all messages in a mailbox using PEAR

Tags: php, email, pear

I am very new to PHP's PEAR extension, and was wondering how to use PEAR to list all of the messages in a mailbox. I have successfully made a program that can find your most recent message, but I want to make it so that it can list all of your messages in your mailbox. I believe this would be done using the pop3 part of PEAR, but am not sure how to go about doing it. Does anybody have any ideas? Is this possible to do with PEAR? 
I currently have this code to list the most recent message:

```
            //create pear object
    require_once 'Net/POP3.php';
    $pop3 =& new Net_POP3();

    //connect to email provider
    if(PEAR::isError($ret = $pop3->connect($host, $port))){
        throw new ConnException($ret->getMessage());
    }

    if(PEAR::isError($ret = $pop3->login($user, $pass, 'USER'))){
        throw new ConnException($ret->getMessage());
    }

    //get num messages and mailbox size
    echo $pop3->numMsg() . ' messages in mailbox, ' . $pop3->getSize() . ' bytes <br/>';

    //get the headers for the most recent message
    if($pop3->numMsg() > 0){
        $msgData = $pop3->getParsedHeaders($pop3->numMsg());
        echo 'The most recent email in your inbox is from ' .htmlentities($msgData['From']) . ' with the subject \'' . htmlentities($msgData['Subject'])  . '\'';
    }

    //disconnect from the provider
    $pop3->disconnect();
```

Could somebody give me some tips, or code, that will modify this to list all the messages in the mailbox?
Thanks!

Comment: @YourCommonSense like what? We aren't supposed to chat here, so talk to me here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31188/php-help-for-new-programmers

Comment: @YourCommonSense Like i said: You cannot chat here. Use the link I sent.... I will now flag your chat comment for moderator review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply show all emails just loop over them.

```php
<?php
//get num messages and mailbox size
$messageCount = $pop3->numMsg();
echo $messageCount . ' messages in mailbox, ' . $pop3->getSize() . ' bytes <br/>';

//get the headers for all messages
// NOTE: need to be careful not to overflow the memory (Only grab the latest 500, etc)
for ($i = $messageCount; $i > 0; $i--) {
    $msgData = $pop3->getParsedHeaders($i);
    echo "Message: $i \n";
    echo "   From: " . htmlentities($msgData['From']) . "\n";
    echo "Subject: " . htmlentities($msgData['Subject']) . "\n";
    echo "-------------------------------------------------\n";
}
```

Comment: okay cool. is it possible to print out the message with the subject?